# Is it ok for electrical wires to run underneath a beam in a basement?

Tags: electrical

**Question:** Is it OK for electrical wires to run underneath main beam of prefab house to get from one side to the other?

The picture shows what has been done by an electrician before I bought the house, so I’m assuming it’s OK.

I just wanted to be sure, because I’m finishing the unfinished basement now and I’ll have all of my work inspected by the county or state. I want to do the same thing instead of having to drill through 10” of beam.

The current is in the storage/utility room and I would be only doing this in that same room. Everything else I’m running in that room would be running through the joists, it’s just getting from one side of the house to the other is my concern.

[image]

Comment: Yes, in Denmark it is ok.

Comment: Do you have more pictures?   I have not seen that type of beam used in a basement in a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Since it is in a basement it could be run along the bottom, per code 334.15.A. My state requires protection in a crawl space along the bottom.